# What are some beginner quantitative option trading strategies?

Tags: options, option-pricing, quant-trading-strategies, python

I'm new to quantitative trading, with good knowledge in finance and coding (mainly Python, Java, R, etc).

I would like to know if there are any basic quantitative option trading strategies that can be coded in Python.

I have a basic understanding of statistics, L.Algebra and Machine learning. Are there any basic options trading strategies that can get me started in quant trading.

Thanks!

Comment: Food for thoughts: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/41695/risk-management-tools-for-long-term-gamma-vega-sellers-subject-to-margin-calls/41747#41747

Comment: If you are interested in doing a programming project about options for learning purposes you might consider doing a simulation of a delta-hedged option, using actual stock price data. You could investigate how the hedging error varies with re-hedging frequency, with the assumed volatility, etc.

Answer (score 4):

There are lot of strategies. You can try for example:

- [Active Collar strategy](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1507991)
- [Calendar Option Strategies](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2871616)
- [Dispersion trading](https://quantpedia.com/Screener/Details/237)

Try to google more, or look for strategies on ssrn.com or arxiv.org ...

Answer (score 2):

If you have a good understanding of call option, put option, options greeks and volatility, then you can try some of these strategies:

1. Covered call/put
2. Bull/ Bear spread
3. Strangle
4. Straddle
5. Butterfly spread
6. Iron condor

Intermediate

7. [Calendar Spread](https://blog.quantinsti.com/calendar-spread-options-trading-strategy/)

Advanced

8. [Dispersion trading](https://blog.quantinsti.com/dispersion-trading-using-options/) (Correlation trading)